# ssis 2012 load flat file with different sized records

Tags: sql, ssis

I am just starting out with SSIS, and have been given the following issue to deal with:

I have a master/detail (of sorts) flat file that has been exported from a VMS application (zero percent chance of getting the file re-formatted, or having the output provided in a different manner).  The file contents are positionally defined (and I have the file definitions to work from, thankfully), like this

```
HD01 - Header record - 82 positions, 12 columns
IN01 - Invoice header - 438 positions, 54 columns
IN02 - Credit Note header - 438 positions, 33 columns
IN03 - Invoice detail - 507 positions, 41 columns
IN04 - Credit detail - 164 positions, 46 columns
```

HD01 only appears once at the top of the file, while IN01 - IN04 appear multiple times.

I can load the data file using a flat file source connection, but I need to load all record types into their respective destination tables.  The best I've been able to do is read the file, and put the contents of each record type into a staging table of sorts, where each table has 2 columns: the record type (HD01, IN01, etc), and the rest of the corresponding line from the data file, however the character translation from the data file to the table results in odd characters (ie: black blocks where dates should be).

I guess my question is two-fold:
1 - how can I split the source data file into 5 destination tables properly, utilizing the data formats I know?
2 - what is going on with my character translation?

Comment: is it possible to give some data as well ? are you going to receive IN01 prefix for each row of its type ?

Comment: Can't provide sample data (highly proprietary), but yes each prefix appears on each line, so the first 4 characters of any line will be its record type

Comment: Have you tried reading the file using flatfile source and the extract first 4 char in derived col and later using conditional split just send the records to 5 destination ?

Comment: As I mentioned, I can get a 2-column table for each of the record types:  Col_1 is the record type, Col_2 is everything else on the line.  The issue I have with that is how do I then split out Col_2 to the rest of the record definition?

Answer (score 0):

> 1 - how can I split the source data file into 5 destination tables
>   properly, utilizing the data formats I know?

I believe, in this case, if output format is more or less fixed, parsing of the lines into separate values and loading data into staging table is a way to go.

As example:

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE (line varchar(255));

INSERT INTO @Table1 VALUES 
( 'HD01 - Header record - 82 positions, 12 columns'),
( 'IN01 - Invoice header - 438 positions, 54 columns'),
( 'IN02 - Credit Note header - 438 positions, 33 columns'),
( 'IN03 - Invoice detail - 507 positions, 41 columns'),
( 'IN04 - Credit detail - 164 positions, 46 columns')

SELECT LEFT(line,4) AS LineTypeCoded
, SUBSTRING(line, 8, CHARINDEX('-', line, 10)-8)  AS LineTypeDescription
, SUBSTRING(line, 2+CHARINDEX('-', line, CHARINDEX('-', line)+1), CHARINDEX('position', line) - 2-CHARINDEX('-', line, CHARINDEX('-', line)+1)) AS Positions
, LTRIM(REPLACE(REPLACE(SUBSTRING(line, CHARINDEX(',', line, CHARINDEX('position', line))+1, 100), 'column', ''), 's', '')) AS Columns
,line AS EntireLine
FROM @Table1
```

or more elegant way:

```
SELECT 
    PARSENAME(calc.line1, 4) AS LineTypeCoded
,   PARSENAME(calc.line1, 3) AS LineTypeDescription
,   PARSENAME(calc.line1, 2) AS  Positions
,   PARSENAME(calc.line1, 1) AS  PositionsColumns
,   line1 AS EntireLine
FROM @Table1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(line, ' - ', '.'),', ', '.'), 'columns', ''), 'positions', '') AS line1
    ) calc
```

So the final result is like:

[image: ssms output]

When data is parsed and in a staging table distribution of rows into 5 differential tables in is a trivial task

> 2 - what is going on with my character translation?

Its look like you code-page issues. Collation of the database is to be matched with a file codepage